# Validar si un objeto es nulo

Tags: kotlin, null

Estoy trabajando en **Kotlin** con con un objeto nulo, y quiero validarlo.
`lateinit var objeto : Object? = null if(objeto?.equals(null)){ //Action }`

Comment: if (objeto == null)

Answer (score 0):

**Para validar si un objeto tiene valor `null` en `Kotlin`**, puedes usar el [**operador  "?.let"**](https://kotlin-quick-reference.com/158-R-let-operator.html), de esta forma:

```
 objeto?.let { println("NO es NULL") } ?: println("es NULL")
```

esto sería equivalente a

```
if(objeto != null){println("NO es NULL") }else{println("es NULL") }
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
    private var objeto : Object? = null

    fun main() {
  
        objeto = Object()
 
        objeto?.let { println("1. NO es NULL") } ?: println("1. es NULL")  
          
        objeto = null
        
        objeto?.let { println("2. NO es NULL") } ?: println("2. es NULL")  
        
   }
```

Salida:

```
1. NO es NULL
2. es NULL
```